# Startegy for organzing the endpoints in SPA app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, vue.js, single-page-application

I need strategy on organizing the urls.

Our application has around 150 urls. Some are rather simple without any Route parameters. While others have often more than 1 route parameter in them. For example it could be like this

1. `api/School/Class`
2. `api/School/1/Class/2/Student`
3. `api/School/Class/revaluate`

So in the first one it has no parameter , while second has two parameters and finally third one has 1 but last part is not a resource but an action.

I don't want to store the url just where we would consume it, since maintaining the urls would be technical nightmare. I was hoping if we could have single file `api.js` or multiple files like `api/School.js` , `api/Teacher.js` for storing the files.

Answer (score 0):

In express, you call this a router.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const schoolRouter = require('./routers/school');

//...

app.use('/api/school', schoolRouter); // Forwards any requests to the schoolrouter

//...
```

School.js:

```
// The router works just like express app (which is also a router)
const schools = require('express').Router();

// we used example.com/api/schools/something to get here
// but the router only cares about what comes next
schools.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  // res.send()
});
    
// Get a single school (etc, you get the point)
schools.get('/:schoolId', function(req, res, next) {
  let id = req.params.schoolId;
  // get data from server and res.send()
});

//...


module.exports = schools;
```

And you can chain routers, but because you only have a partial route, parameters might get lost. So the normal thing is to store parameters to the `req` object.

```
schools.use('/:schoolId/classes', function(req, res, next) {
  req.schoolId = req.params.schoolId;
  next()
}, classesRouter);
```

This way we can access `req.schoolId` at any time further down the chain.